# Can I get an ebike with a 500 watt motor in Australia?

Tags: electric-bike, australia

I'm a bit on the heavy side, so I'd like to purchase an ebike with something a little gutsier than the usual 250 watt motor so that I can go up hills. Can these be purchased in Australia at all?

Comment: You can - how about 5200W - all you need somewhere to ride it that will not end up in conversations with the local Police.  https://www.electricbikesuperstore.com.au/Stealth-B-52

Comment: @mattnz Wow. I want that.

Comment: @Odyssee What's the point? It weighs 53kg so you're never going to want to use the pedals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I ride trial, mountain/road bike and BMX a lot. From the looks of it, you can handle it like a trial bike on steroids. It also can go backwards without engaging the cassette like a freecoaster on a BMX. Imagine all the possibilities! As a normal commuter bike, this is a no go.

Comment: Thanks guys, though I'm really after more of a commuter that wouldn't look out of place, not an electric motorcycle. I'm considering this: https://pirez.com.au/36v-500w-mid-drive-electric-bike-blue/

Comment: Have you given the '250W' bikes a try?  There is a difference between a 250W motor and a motor software-limited to sustained steady state output of 250W.  I'm 90+KG and have no trouble keeping up with my wife's "500W" bike on a Bosch CX  (especially if you're respecting the max assisted speed limit regulation as well)

Comment: Hi Affe. Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit heavier than you and there are some steep hills in my area. It's not about wanting to go faster than 25 km/h, I just want a descent amount of assistance in going up hill and a 200 watt machine I tried in the past really struggled. I also really want a motor at the crank rather than the wheel hub so the power can be geared to keep the motor's RPMs up in its torque band.

Answer (score 2):

A 500W motor is not currently legal for use in Australia.

*"In Australia the e-bike is defined by the Australian Vehicle Standards as a bicycle that has an auxiliary motor with a maximum power output not exceeding 200 W without consideration for speed limits or pedal sensors.[1] Each state is responsible for deciding how to treat such a vehicle and currently all states agree that such a vehicle does not require licensing or registration. Various groups are lobbying for an increase in this low limit to encourage more widespread use of e-bikes to assist in mobility, health benefits and to reduce congestion, pollution and road danger. Some states have their own rules such as no riding under electric power on bike paths and through built up areas so riders should view the state laws regarding their use. There is no licence and no registration required for e-bike usage.*

*Since 30 May 2012, Australia has an additional new e-bike category using the European Union model of a pedelec as per the CE EN15194 standard. This means the e-bike can have a motor of 250W of continuous rated power which can only be activated by pedalling (if above 6 km/h) and must cut out over 25 km/h – if so it is classed as a normal bicycle. The state of Victoria is the first to amend their local road rules, see below."*

Quoted text from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_bicycle_laws#Australia

Comment: Presumably, anything above that is classed as an electric motorbike and requires appropriate licencing, insurance and so on, whether it has pedals or not.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.stealthelectricbikes.com/ Australian made, very powerful ebikes.

Comment: That's already mentioned in the comments. We're usually looking for answers taht are more than just a link -- at least a short paragraph explaining why the link is relevant. For example, what does "very powerful" mean?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Bit over the top for my needs as I'm after a commuter. :-)